# Passing multiple viewmodels to a component - performance issues?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.2

Using knockout.js components I'm wondering if performance get affected when passing multiple viewmodels to a component instead of just a single one.

Having the following:

```
function masterViewModel(){
    this.demo = new demoViewModel().init();
    this.demo2 = new demo2ViewModel().init();
    this.demo3 = new demo3ViewModel().init();
    this.demo4 = new demo4ViewModel().init();
    this.demo5 = new demo5ViewModel().init();
    this.demo6 = new demo6ViewModel().init();
}

var mm = new masterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mm, $(':root').get(0));
```

I was thinking of passing the whole masterViewModel variable to my component in order to be able to access all viewmodels from it:

```
ko.components.register(element, {
    viewModel: { instance: mm },
    template: { require: 'text!views/myComponent.html' },
});
```

Would performance get affected in a bad way if I do that instead of just passing a single viewmodel?

```
ko.components.register(element, {
    viewModel: { instance: mm.demo3 },
    template: { require: 'text!views/myComponent.html' },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will there be any noticeable performance difference between `register` option 1 and 2? No. With just the code you've presented, the two options are nearly equivalent, except for one *instance* of the `.` operator. Negligable.

Knockout will *not* AFAIK walk the entire view model object graph to take action (e.g. subscribe to observable changes), it just keeps a reference to the view model instance.

Apart from that very direct answer to the question: performance is context dependent. If you have doubts which option is faster: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: I'm not worried about the operator itself, but about how Knockout.js deals with the viewModels when passing them to a component. As 7 big viewmodels are much more logic than just 1. But it seems you've replied that as well.